# Github Issue and travis returning errors

Tags: python, django, github, travis-ci

I'm a student participating in Google Code-In.

There's a task in which I need to fix [this issue](https://github.com/openwisp/netdiff/issues/58) on GitHub. My Travis build is failing and here's [my PR](https://github.com/openwisp/netdiff/pull/68). An exception need to be raised and I must check for it.

I don't really want everything given to me, just some kind of help so that I can move forward.

Comment: Btw, I'm not too experienced with python. It's the first time that I'm doing all this and doing tests. It's also my first Stack Overflow question, so sorry if I wrote anything noobish or stuff in this post.

Comment: You have errors in your code. You should check the [travis build output](https://travis-ci.org/openwisp/netdiff/jobs/465865189)

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah, I checked the [travis build output](https://travis-ci.org/openwisp/netdiff/jobs/465865189) but I don't know how to fix these errors. Added some exceptions to ignore for flake8 but they are still reported in Travis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the test wrongly and I was catching an exception that wasn't being raised. Finally fixed it. Thanks for the responses still!